# problem showing PDF in Blazor page from byte array

Tags: pdf, byte, blazor

I have gone through all the suggestions for how to take a byte array stored in SQL Server db as `varbinary` and display it as PDF in a Blazor website. I'm successful in ASP.Net with the aspx pages and code behind but I can't seem to find the right combination for Blazor (`ShowPDF.razor` and code behind `ShowPDF.razor.cs`)

Here is what I have as variants in the code behind:

1. The aReport.ReportDocument is returning a byte array of aReport.DocumentSize from the DB

   ```
    FileStreamResult GetPDF()
    {
        var pdfStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        this.rdb = new ReportData();
        aReport = rdb.GetWithReport(1);

        pdfStream.Write(aReport.ReportDocument, 0, aReport.DocumentSize);
        pdfStream.Position = 0;
        return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf"));
    }
   ```

OR 2. direct binary array to base 64 encoding:

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(aReport.ReportDocument);
```

While those two processes return the data, I'm unable to find how to set up the razor page to show the result. I have tried:

```
<object src="@Url.Action("GetPDF")"/>
```

and other variants without success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I finally found the resolution for this.
The ShowPDF.razor.cs code behind page is:

```cs
public partial class ShowPDF: ComponentBase
{
    private IReportData rdb;       // the database
    private ReportModel aReport;   // report model 

    /*
    aReport.ReportDocument holds the byte[]
    */
    string GetPDF(int ReportId)
    {
        this.rdb = new ReportData();
        aReport = rdb.GetWithReport(ReportId);
        return "data:application/pdf;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(aReport.ReportDocument);
    }
}
```

### and the ShowPDF.razor page is:

```
@page "/ShowPDF"
@page "/ShowPDF/{Report:int}"


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Report { get; set; }
}
<embed src="@GetPDF(Report)" visible="false" width="1500" height="2000" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid this solution is not optimal for medium size or large PDF files. Nobody sets systematically image source as base64 string. It should be the same for PDF files. Browsers will appreciate downloading PDF in a separate thread not in the HTML code rendering.

In Blazor, this can be easy achieved using a [custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/middleware).

```
namespace MyMiddlewares
{
    public class ShowPdf
    {
        public ShowPdf(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            //_next = next; no call to _next.Invoke(context) because the handler is at the end of the request pipeline, so there will be no next middleware to invoke.
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            byte[] pdfBytes = getPdfFromDb(context.Request.Query["pdfid"]);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

            context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition",
                                "attachment; " +
                                "filename=\"mypdf.pdf\"; " +
                                "size=" + pdfBytes.Length + "; " +
                                "creation-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("R").Replace(",", "") + "; " +
                                "modification-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("R").Replace(",", "") + "; " +
                                "read-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("R").Replace(",", ""));
            await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(pdfBytes);
        }
    }

    public static class ShowPdfExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseShowPdf(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<ShowPdf>();
        }
    }
}
```

In the `Configure` method of Startup.cs, you add (before `app.UseStaticFiles();`)

```
app.MapWhen(
    context => context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("ShowPdf.mdwr", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase),
    appBranch => {
        appBranch.UseShowPdf();
    });
```

So, this URL will download a PDF file: `/ShowPdf.mdwr?pdfid=idOfMyPdf`

If embedding is required, this URL may be used in a PDF viewer.

Comment: Thanks.
I totally agree with you and I tried to find a way in Blazor to use context.Response and all that but never managed to and because there are historically large pdf files in the DB, I needed to reply to the user with a link to a web location with a .Net aspx page. 

I'm not familiar with the middle ware concept and just copying and pasting your solution that you kindly provided doesn't help me either until I understand more.

Again thanks for the direction and if you are available for paid help, please contact me at wbaeck@earthlink.net

Comment: I finally had the time to learn about the middle ware concept and implemented this solution you provided. Thank you very much!